# Is there a function to sort a Table in MS Report Designer for a String like xx.xx.x.xxx.x.xx?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, columnsorting

I do have a report for BOM that receives a so called "RowOrder" from a SQL query.

The report pops up correctly, but I want to change the sorting of the rows:

[image: actual row sorting]

If there is now the row order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3

I do want the row order instead: 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4, 5

How can I achieve this?

The BOM Information comes from Autodesk Vault SQL Server, and I am editing with MS Visual Studio 2015. This is a RDLC report.

Comment: The easiest way, I think, would be to convert all the numbers to a decimal. So it would look like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, etc. Would this be an acceptable format? If so, you can simply multiply the roworder by 1.0 (`select roworder * 1.0`)

Comment: Thank you, BUT: the nesting depth is not limited to 2 . Maybe there is something like:3.2.5.10.21.3. This is the value for one row.

Comment: What is the datatype of this roworder column?

Comment: It is a string, I presume.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it were a string, but nonetheless, I was able to get the ordering you are seeking by using a CAST to convert that column to a float datatype.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Doing a simple select shows the order is off, but when adding the `ORDER BY 1`, it orders as you are seeking.

```
CREATE TABLE #test(row FLOAT)

INSERT INTO #test
VALUES(1), (2), (2.2), (2.3), (4), (3)

SELECT *
FROM #test
ORDER BY 1
```

So the solution would be to alter your query to change the datatype.

```
CAST(RowOrder as float)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for a similar task that converts the dot notation to a bigint which you can then sort. The expected parts and max part length shoudl be set to values as small as possible although the function can handle a 3 part number even if you say expected parts is 4 (it will just add more zeros).

This function will fail if there are many long parts but for my purposes it worked fine. If it fails for you, you could modify it to return the string value instead of casting it to a bigint (the last line of code).

**note** this uses a split function (code also supplied) . I'm not sure if you could use the SQL2016> string_split function instead but I wrote this years ago.

---

[fn].[ConvertDotNotationToInteger] code

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[ConvertDotNotationToInteger] (@dotNumber varchar(256), @expectedParts int = 4, @MaxPartLength int = 4)
RETURNS bigint 
AS
BEGIN

-- if @dotNumber contains less parts than the expected number append '.0' to the end
declare @foundParts bigint
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fn.split(@dotNumber, '.')) < @expectedParts
    BEGIN
        SET @dotNumber = @dotNumber + '.00'
    END

declare @rStr varchar(256) = ''
SELECT @rstr = @rstr + right('00000000'+ rtrim(value), @MaxPartLength) from fn.split(@dotNumber, '.')

RETURN cast(@rStr as bigint)

END
```

---

fn.split t-sql code

---

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [fn].[Split](@sText varchar(8000), @sDelim varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @retArray TABLE (idx smallint Primary Key, value varchar(8000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @idx smallint,
    @value varchar(8000),
    @bcontinue bit,
    @iStrike smallint,
    @iDelimlength tinyint
IF @sDelim = 'Space'
    BEGIN
    SET @sDelim = ' '
    END
SET @idx = 0
SET @sText = LTrim(RTrim(@sText))
SET @iDelimlength = DATALENGTH(@sDelim)
SET @bcontinue = 1
IF NOT ((@iDelimlength = 0) or (@sDelim = 'Empty'))
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue = 1
        BEGIN
--If you can find the delimiter in the text, retrieve the first element and
--insert it with its index into the return table.
 
        IF CHARINDEX(@sDelim, @sText)>0
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1, CHARINDEX(@sDelim,@sText)-1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            
--Trim the element and its delimiter from the front of the string.
            --Increment the index and loop.
SET @iStrike = DATALENGTH(@value) + @iDelimlength
            SET @idx = @idx + 1
            SET @sText = LTrim(Right(@sText,DATALENGTH(@sText) - @iStrike))
        
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
--If you can't find the delimiter in the text, @sText is the last value in
--@retArray.
 SET @value = @sText
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            --Exit the WHILE loop.
SET @bcontinue = 0
            END
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue=1
        BEGIN
        --If the delimiter is an empty string, check for remaining text
        --instead of a delimiter. Insert the first character into the
        --retArray table. Trim the character from the front of the string.
--Increment the index and loop.
        IF DATALENGTH(@sText)>1
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1,1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            SET @idx = @idx+1
            SET @sText = SUBSTRING(@sText,2,DATALENGTH(@sText)-1)
            
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            --One character remains.
            --Insert the character, and exit the WHILE loop.
            INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
            VALUES (@idx, @sText)
            SET @bcontinue = 0  
            END
    END
END
RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you need explicit string conversion function for the order expression like this:

=CStr(Fields!rowOrder.Value)

[image: report order expression]